# What is the Big-O complexity of the function2?

Tags: python, big-o, complexity-theory

I found these two functions:

```
""" returns a list of the items in map """
def function1(map):
        a = list()
        for item in map:
            a.add(item)
        return a

""" hypothetical function """
def function2(map):
        b = list()
        for item1 in map.function1():
            for item2 in map.function1():
                if (xxxxx):
                   b.add(item2)
        return b
```

I was trying to determine the big O complexity for both these functions. 
I would say function1 has O(n) complexity and function2 has O(n^2) but I am not sure about function2's complexity as it is calling the function1 in each for cycle.

Thank you so much for your help! :D

Comment: Why do you have a variable with the same name as the built-in function `map`? Are these both methods in a class, i.e. is the function `function1` here the same as the method `map.function1()` that's called in `function2`? If so, where is the class declaration and why isn't the parameter called `self`? If not, what type of thing is `map`? And what is the missing condition `xxxxx`?

Comment: `list` doesn't have an `add` method, either.

Comment: It also appears `function1` could simply be `return list(map)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're exactly right that function2 has `O(n^2)` complexity. As you note, it is calling function1 in each cycle of the for loop. By calling an `O(n)` function `n` times it becomes `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

Function2 would be O(n^2). Yes, function1 is linear in size of the map, but so is iterating through the values, which prevents this from becoming O(n^3) or O(n^4).

There are a couple of problems with this code though, you need to do `function1(map)`, not `map.function1()`, since `function1` is not a method of `map`. Further, this can be accomplished in Python by simply iterating through the items in the map like so:

```
def function2(map):
    b = list()
    for item1 in map:
        for item2 in map:
            if (xxxxx):
                b.append(item2)
    return b
```

This can actually be further simplified using list comprehension to:

```
def function2(map):
    return [item2 for item1 in map for item2 in map if xxxxx]
```

Edit: Updated list comprehension